# How do you turn off auto-capitalisation in HTML form fields in iOS?

Tags: ios, html

By default, iOS’s keyboard sets the first letter in text form fields (including `type=email`) to uppercase. (At least prior to iOS 5.)

Is there any way to disable the autocapitalization?

Answer (score 342, accepted):

Since iOS 5, `type="email"` has auto-capitalization disabled automatically, so you simply need:

```
<input type="email">
```

For other input types, there are attributes available that do what they say:

```
<input type="text" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none">
```

If for some reason you want to support iOS prior to version 5, use this for `type="email"`:

```
<input type="email" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none">
```

More information:

- [iOS Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-autocapitalize)
- [Controlling which iOS keyboard is shown](http://sja.co.uk/2012/1/4/controlling-which-ios-keyboard-is-shown)

Comment: I think this is a bit outdated now. When I do type="email" on iOS 5, autocapitalize is disabled.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert Can confirm. 2014 and we can hardly remember iOS 6.

Comment: Use `autocapitalize="none"` instead of `autocapitalize="off"` because `"off"` is deprecated for `autocapitalize`. See [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/Attributes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008058-autocapitalize).

Comment: Any suggestions for doing this on Android devices?

Comment: I love how fast one finds 'the answer' online. thanks @thirtydot!

Comment: Has anyone managed to do this in an Ionic app? Trying to prevent sentence case in a ion-searchbar and I can't seem to get autocapitalize="off" to work. I think it doesn't work by default because the input field it generates within doesn't apply the attributes for you..

Comment: @JGFMK: You could try setting [the `type` to `email`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/searchbar/Searchbar/#input-properties). If that doesn't work or is otherwise not suitable try looking through [these issues](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=autocapitalize) or making a new issue over there.

Comment: It seems that for `autocapitalize` there isn't much support as per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/autocapitalize)

Comment: Not working in Firefox 98 for Android (2022). Type=email works, but then the tooltip asks you to enter an email... This can be overwritten with setting also `title="your title"`.

Answer (score 9):

Just as a heads up, if you're looking at this example and you're using React Native, you'll want to use those props as camelcase.

`autoCapitalize`

and

`autoCorrect`

This confused me a bit until I looked at the [React Native Documentation for Text Inputs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput#autocapitalize).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative "safe but brutal" one-liner to stop the input capitalization:

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value = this.value.charAt(0).toLowerCase()+this.value.slice(1);">
```

Works like a charm, with all credit to [this website](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/input-field-uppercase/)!!