# How do you turn off auto-capitalisation in HTML form fields for mobile browsers?

Tags: android, html, ios, forms

While searching for a solution, I have found this [question about auto-capitalisation on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5171764/607407). I have chosen a solution:

`autocapitalize="off"`

However on my phone (Android with Firefox 29.0.1) this does not work at all. When I enter the field, the Shift key is pressed and I have to un-press it.

So what's (or what are) solution(s) for all major browsers and systems?

Comment: I think we'll have to wait HTML6 :)

Comment: Aren't there any non-conventional solutions that could be mixed together to satisfy individual platform needs?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think so, but you should keep that autocapitalize=off cause it could work even on android some days. Also, you should try some others browsers.

Comment: I just tested this in Firefox for Android. The `autocapitalize="off"` and `autocapitalize="none"` attributes still have no effect on `search` inputs, but at least this has now been added to the HTML Standard, so Mozilla is enticed to implement it.