# First letter in android keyboard, in an html input text, to lowercase

Tags: android-softkeyboard

I'd like the first letter on the android keyboard to appear lowercase when a user taps on a html text input

Comment: This will do it: `<input type="text" autocapitalize="none">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5171812/4575543

I found this answer. Seems to work (but apparently not for all keyboard apps on android and not all older browsers).
At least iOS is covering it and Chrome since version 43: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/autocapitalize

Additionally I set the css property `text-transform: lowercase;` and convert the input value on `keyup` with `value.toLowerCase()` – just in case.