# Issue having a popup that make the first letter capital in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tauri

I am working with react and typescript for building a macOS application. I am using MUI text field and every-time I enter a text in the field there is a pop up showing to change the first letter to caps and when I press spacebar it changes the first letter to caps.

[Image of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wERXK.png)

Tried the autoComplete tag didn't help and also looked into other solutions but nothing helped. The auto capitalise of first letter should not popup.

```
export const TextInputField: React.FC<Props> = ({ inputLabel, inputValue, ...props }) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation()

  const [isFocused, setFocused] = useState(false)

  function onFocus (): void { setFocused(true) }
  function onBlur (): void { setFocused(false) }

  const isInputValueEmpty: boolean = inputValue === ''

  return (
    <TextField
      label={isFocused || !isInputValueEmpty ? '' : t(inputLabel)} size='small'
      {...props}
      InputProps={inputPropsStyle}
      onFocus={onFocus}
      onBlur={onBlur}
    />
  )
}

const inputPropsStyle = {
  style: {
    height: '30px',
    width: '220px',
    borderRadius: '4px',
    fontFamily: 'IBM',
    fontSize: FontSize.IBMCaption,
    background: Colours.BG800,
    borderColor: 'transparent',
    color: Colours.BG400
  }
}
```

This is the implementation of the text field component above

```
export const UserNameContainer: React.FC = () => {
  const userNameReducer = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.userNameReducer)
  const disableEmailReducer = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.disableEmailReducer)

  const userName: string = userNameReducer.userName
  const isEmailDisabled: boolean = disableEmailReducer.isEmailDisabled

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const { setUserName } = bindActionCreators(userNameActionCreator, dispatch)

  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <TextInputFieldTitle title='userName' />
      <TextInputField
        disabled={isEmailDisabled}
        inputLabel='yourEmail'
        onChange={(val) => setUserName(val.currentTarget.value)}
        type='email'
        inputValue={userName} />
    </div >
  )
}

const containerStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
  display: 'flex',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  paddingTop: '25px'
}
```

Comment: This could be due to the value given for the `type` attribute in the `input` tag, please update your question to include code and the issue as text (and not solely as images)

Comment: @Harrison I have added the code, could you please have a look and let me know, what the issue could be.

Comment: Hm, looks like this might end up being a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171764/how-do-you-turn-off-auto-capitalisation-in-html-form-fields-in-ios , with the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52956534/15291770